# No Unity Launcher in Ubuntu 11 Beta?

Tags: unity, 11.04

I just upgraded from 10.10, and I don't have a launcher at all.
How can I add it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! 11.04 is currently in Beta so things might not work right. Please file a bug on this issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the beta release, see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32925/my-unity-launcher-and-panel-have-disappeared-in-11-04-how-do-i-get-them-to-show

Answer (score 0):

I did both a full install and upgrade from Maverick, both from the Beta1 .iso. Neither system displayed a launcher until the nvidia driver was installed via `jockey-gtk`.

I don't know that this is essential, but it was sufficient for my installs.